# How to integrate the remember me option to a login form with Php and Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, session-cookies, remember-me

I have been trying to integrate the remember me option to my login form, using php and Ajax call, but can't seem to find my way around it. Probably messing up with cookies. The login page is working fine, but when the remember me option is checked, the login page just reloads after submission. Below is my current code;

**Html form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
    session_start();
        if( isset($_SESSION['patient_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['username']))
            {
                header('location: patient-details.php');
            }
?>


<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Outer Row -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-3 col-md-3">

        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
          <div class="card-body p-0">
            <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="p-5">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Kabi Medical Records</h1>
                    <h7 class="h7 text-gray-900 mb-4">Log in to continue.</h7>
                  </div>
                  <form class="user" method = "POST" id="loginform"">
                      <hr>
                       <div id="loginmessage"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="UserName" aria-describedby="username" placeholder="User Name" name="username" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="UserPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="remember" value="yes">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Remember Me</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
               <button type="submit" id="userloginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" name="login">Login</button>
                    
                  </form>
                  <hr>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="small" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="small" href="/kabirecords">Back to Home</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
  <script src="assets/js/l.js"></script>
  
  

</body>

</html>
```

**Login.php**

```
    <?php
 
 //Start session
 
    session_start();
    
   //Connect to the database
   
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb") or die(mysqli_error());

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $remember = $_POST['remember'];

    //Run query: Check combinaton of usernamel & password exists
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_patients WHERE username='$username' && password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

  
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
    { 

   //If username & password don't match print error

   
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   
    if ($count !== 1) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong Username or Password</div>';
    } 


   else {
 
      
   //log the user in: Set session variables and Cookies
   
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   
    
       if($remember == "yes") { 
                setcookie('username', $row['username'] , time()+(60*60*24*7), ""); 
                setcookie('password', $row['password'] , time()+(60*60*24*7), ""); 
            }
            else { 
            
             $_SESSION['patient_id'] = $row['patient_id'];
             $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            }
            
            
    echo "success";
   
     }
   }     
 
  else {
     
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Both are Required Fields </div>'; 
    } 
 
 ?>
```

**Login.js**

```
    <script>

    $("#loginform").submit(function(event) {
    //prevent default php processing
    event.preventDefault();
    //collect user inputs
    var datatopost = $(this).serializeArray();
    //send them to login.php using AJAX
      $.ajax({
      url: "login.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: datatopost,
      success: function(data) {
          if ($.trim(data) === "success") {
              Swal.fire({
              icon: 'success',
              title: 'Login successful',
            });
          window.location = "patient-details.php";
        } else {
          $("#loginmessage").html(data);
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        $("#loginmessage").html(
          "<div class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error with the Ajax Call. Please try again later.</div>"
        );$
      }
    });
  });

 </script>
```